# i changed the function name but still getting this Cannot redeclare geting_Ip() (previously declared in C:\xampp\htdocs

Tags: php

```
function geting_Ip() {
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    } elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }

    return $ip;
}
```

Comment: where are you using this as and how is it included/required? the error's pretty obvious

Comment: yes i am calling this in a function                                                                                   function cart_page() {

 global $connect;
 if (isset($_GET['add_cart'])) {
 
 $ip_addrs=geting_Ip();
 $product_id= $_GET['add_cart'];

 $qry="SELECT * FROM cart WHERE p_id='$product_id' AND ip_address='$ip_addrs'";